# iOS App Distribution - xcode12 - Code signing "Bolts.framework" failed

Tags: app-store-connect, carthage, xcode12, bolts-framework

In xcode12 when I try to upload to itunesconnect for an app using:
bolts-framework
parse-framework

I get the error 'Code signing "Bolts.framework" failed.'

The app uses carthage for the frameworks. The app runs on the simulator and devices but fails on upload to the store.

Comment: There is an update for carthage: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md

Answer (score 0):

There is an workaround for Carthage that works - https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md